# How to write a Mp3 clipper or cutter in android?

Tags: android, activerecord, mp3, media-player, audio-recording

I am writing an application which will cut the part of the Mp3 song which is being played. User may select from the mid of the song to the next selection. Currently i am playing the audio file using the MediaPlayer and on selecting the user i have to start recording the playing song.

Will anyone please help me with any information you got regarding the recording of the playback song.

Its similar to Mp3 Cutter.

**If anyone knows how to extract the audio frames from an mp3 file, please let me know.**

Thanks & Regards,
Suman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an R&D R&D R&D and googling googling googling.....
I came to know that, there is no support from the android for extracting the frames of the audio.....
We need to write our own clipper.....

For implementing the clipper
1) Steady the codec
2) Take the sync code of the Codec and extract the frames...
3) Now to try to get the marks and then extract the frames between the marks

Note: Frames mark should be in sync with the playing.

[Example Code](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/source/browse/trunk/?r=66#trunk)

Comment: can you please post your code or link how you achived this just to edit the wave file. In my case i just want to trim(cut) the recording which is saved in wave format. I gone through the above mentioned link but its for all .mp3, .wave etc formats i just need only for wave. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Shivaraj2 I just used that Ring Droid code. You can extract the .wave format processor only in the source code mentioned in the link.

Comment: thank you for ur reply. I am new to android. I am really confused which part of the code i have to add? and where to add in my project? or I have to include ringDroid to my project? i am not getting please help me out to solve this. I have a voice recorder app and i just want to trim the recorded file (.wave) lets say startSec to endSec.