# How can we make part of single audio file. like i want to make two audio files from one audio file in Android.

Tags: android

How can we make part of single audio file. Just like want to make two Audio files from one Audio file from selected position of Audio file in android. so how is it possible please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

[How to write a Mp3 clipper or cutter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109864/how-to-write-a-mp3-clipper-or-cutter-in-android)

And this

https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/source/browse/trunk/?r=66#trunk/src/com/ringdroid